# how to remove additional line created by jtextfield

Tags: java, swing

```
AI: Enter 1 to add question to chatbot.
AI: Enter 2 to start chatting with bot.
AI: Enter 3 to end chatbot.
[You] 1
[You] hi
AI: Hello there!
[You] hi
```

the one above is in GUI jtextarea JFrame, how do i remove the final "[You] hi" that is after the "AI: Hello there!"? only one "hi" is written by jtextfield by me, however it reply 2 "hi". or is there a easier way for me to write a code that can select multiple other class "function" than this?
the following is the code that i have.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUItest2 extends JFrame {

    private JTextField userinput = new JTextField();
    private JTextArea scriptarea = new JTextArea();
    private String stringinput;

    public GUItest2() {
        // Frame Attributes:
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(600, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setTitle("Java AI");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        userinput.setLocation(2, 540);
        userinput.setSize(590, 30);

        scriptarea.setLocation(15, 5);
        scriptarea.setSize(560, 510);
        scriptarea.setEditable(false);

        this.add(userinput);
        this.add(scriptarea);

        selectionfunction();
        // chatfunction();
    }

    public void textarea() {
        // userinput.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        // public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
        stringinput = userinput.getText();
        scriptarea.append("[You] " + stringinput + "\n");
        // }
        // });
    }

    public void selectionfunction() {
        botreply("Enter 1 to add question to chatbot.");
        botreply("Enter 2 to start chatting with bot.");
        botreply("Enter 3 to end chatbot.");
        userinput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textarea();
                if (stringinput.contains("1")) {
                    chatfunction();
                }
                userinput.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    public void chatfunction() {
        userinput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textarea();
                if (stringinput.contains("hi")) {
                    botreply("Hello there!");
                } else if (stringinput.contains("how are you")) {
                    int decider = (int) (Math.random() * 2 + 1);
                    if (decider == 1) {
                        botreply("I'm doing well, thanks");
                    } else if (decider == 2) {
                        botreply("Not too bad");
                    }
                } else {
                    int decider = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 1);
                    if (decider == 1) {
                        botreply("I didn't get that");
                    } else if (decider == 2) {
                        botreply("Please rephrase that");
                    } else if (decider == 3) {
                        botreply("???");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void botreply(String s) {
        scriptarea.append("AI: " + s + "\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUItest2();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons for your problem;

Firstly, you have declare `userinput.addActionListener` twice, which leads to the `textarea()` method being called twice whenever a value is submitted by the text box.

Secondly, you don't reset the `userinput` at the end of the `ActionListener` in the `chatfunction()` method. This is why it prints your original input twice.

Lastly, whenever the `textarea()` method is called, you retrieve the value for userinput and append it to the chat, no matter what it is. Consider adding an if statement to first check if there is input to be appended. e.g. `if(!stringinput.equals("")) scriptarea.append("[You] " + stringinput + "\n");`

As Pshemo said above, there are other issues with the flow of your code you should look to resolve, namely the calling of a new `ActionListener` from within another.